# How can one create dummy variables in pandas that do not have multicollinearity?

Tags: python, macos, pandas, ipython, anaconda

Using Anaconda, Python 2.7.11, pandas 0.17.1, Mac OS X 10.11 (El Capitan), how do you drop a dummy variable from each column that you are making dummy variables out of to avoid multicollinearity (or the dummy variable trap) when fitting to a statistical model?

If one enters:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))
pd.get_dummies(s)
```

Returned is:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  1
3  1  0  0
```

I want to drop a, b, or c columns to avoid multicollinearity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality will be added in pandas version 0.18.0 (currently 0.17.1).  But if you would like this functionality sooner, then you will have to build the pandas library from source.  The following instructions will show you how to do this.  First, in a terminal, uninstall pandas by typing:

```
conda uninstall pandas
```

Then, navigate to site-packages, where Python stores its libraries:

```
cd /Users/[username]/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

where [username] is your username.  The root of this path may be wherever your currently activated Python environment is located, to generalize beyond Anaconda. To reveal where your activated version of python is located, type:

```
which python
```

Enter these commands into terminal to clone into a repo where someone has added extra functionality to the pandas.get_dummies command:

```
git clone https://github.com/BranYang/pandas
cd pandas
python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force
python setup.py install
```

Then, open Python (or IPython):

```
ipython
```

and enter:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(list('abca'))
pd.get_dummies(s, drop_first = True)
```

And this will be displayed:

```
   b  c
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  0  0
```

Thus, pd.get_dummies has dropped your first column and you have avoided the dummy variable trap!